Why is current constant in a series circuit?
This is more of a confirmation I require rather than a direct question, please do guide me though, since I can be terribly wrong. (I do not have much knowledge of this.)
Current is defined as the directed flow of charge in an electric circuit. According to Ohm's Law, I could say that current is directly proportional to voltage and inversely proportional to resistance.
Now, I do know that the electrons cannot pile up since behind and in front of every electron, there exists another. So, if I connect $3$ resistors in series, all with different voltages, the current flowing through them has to be constant, right?
Now, here is my problem: Is it correct to assume that with varying voltages, the current also fluctuates, but varying voltage is due to the presence of resistors (voltage drop, etc), and that current has no part in this?
Let's pretend that the wire is a river and the current is the water flow. Initially, I have $5  \text{A}$ of current with a bulb only (only $1$ resistor). If I add another bulb in the circuit in series that has a much higher resistance than the first, the overall charge would decrease, right? If I measure with an ammeter, would the measure of Coulombs per second decrease as the electrons initially move out of the battery?

Ohm's law can be expressed as $$I = \frac{V}{R}.$$
Clearly changing $V$ or $R$ will change the current, so the idea that current is constant is clearly incorrect.
I think you may be getting confused with the fact that current is the same everywhere in a series circuit. If we use a water analogy, if I push a litre in one end of a full hosepipe a litre of water must come out the other end. If we have a series of hoses connected end to end and some are thin and some are fat, and we put a flow of $3 \ \text{litres per second}$ into the first hose, the water flow will be the $3 \ \text{litres per second}$ in every hose in the circuit, independent of the diameter of each individual hose. The water current is the same everywhere in the circuit. The individual water molecules will be moving slower in the fat hoses, but there are more of them moving in parallel and as a consequence, the flow in terms of litres per second or kilograms per second of water, is the same in every hose.
In the case of the electrical circuit, the number of charges passing a given point in a series circuit, is the same at ever point and in every resistor in the circuit.

If you start out with a circuit that initially contains a battery and a resistor, you will measure a given current:
$$I={V\over R}.$$
If you now add another resistor to the circuit in a series configuration as specified, then the current in the circuit will decrease:
$$I={V\over(R+R^\prime)}.$$
The larger the net resistance becomes, the smaller the current for a given voltage.

Thank you for not turning a blind eye to my stupid question. So, i watched some lectures, to help clear my doubts...and so far, ive come to a small conclusion of my own...given the context, (a series circuit) the current is independent (or is it true for all cases? i dont think it does, cuz no voltage would mean no potential difference for the electrons to move) so in the ohms law, I now acts as a constant, and with V = IR, it can be said that V is directly proportional to R...

@Confusedaf The current in such a circuit is dependent on the ratio of voltage to resistance, so that $$I={V\over R}.$$ If the voltage was zero, $V=0$, then the current would also be zero, $I=0$.

When we say "the current is constant in a series circuit", we mean that the current through the first resistor is the same as the current through the second resistor.
We don't mean that if you change the resistor values the current won't change. We don't mean that if you change the voltage applied the current won't change. We don't mean that if you add additional resistors or remove one of the resistors (replacing it with a short) the current won't change. Because none of those things are true.

Is it correct if I assume that with varying voltages, the current also fluctuates,

Yes. If you vary the source voltage, the current will change proportionally.
But the current through the first resistor will still be the same as the current through the second resistor.

but varying voltage is due to presence of resistors (voltage drop, etc), and that current has no part in this?

I'm not clear on what you mean here, but it is true that for real-world voltage sources, changing the current drawn will (slightly) change the output voltage.
Regardless of this fact, if you put two resistors in series connected to this source (or to any other circuit), then the current through the first resistor will be equal to the current through the second resistor.

Initially, I have 5 A of current with a bulb only (only 1 resistor). If I add another bulb in the circuit in series with much higher resistance than the first the overall charge would decrease, right?

Yes, increasing the equivalent resistance of the load on the source will decrease the current drawn from the source.
But after adding the second bulb in series with the first one, the current through the first bulb and the current through the second bulb will be equal. Not to the current that was originally going through the first bulb, but to the new current determined by the new configuration of the circuit.

I will answer to every point of your question.

Current is defined as the directed flow of charge in an electric circuit. According to Ohm's Law, I could say that current is directly proportional to voltage and inversely proportional to resistance.

Yes, Ohm's law is $V=RI$.

Now, I do know that the electrons cannot pile up since behind and in front of every electron, there exists another. So, if I connect 3 resistors in series, all with different voltages, the current flowing through them has to be constant, right?

Current can circulate only if the circuit is closed, typically a voltage generator is used. At this very basic level, conservation of charge requires current to be the same through all the resistors in series.

Here is my problem. Is it correct if I assume that with varying voltages, the current also fluctuates, but varying voltage is due to presence of resistors (voltage drop, etc.), and that current has no part in this?

Assuming the generator is a voltage generator (in the sense that you can control manually the voltage) then, as a consequence of Ohm's law, current varies accordingly.

Let's assume the wire is a river and the current is the water flow. Initially, I have $5 \,\text{A}$ of current with a bulb only (only 1 resistor). If I add another bulb in the circuit in series with much higher resistance than the first the overall charge would decrease, right? If I measure with an ammeter, so the No. of coulombs per second would decrease as the electrons initially move out of the battery?

What you mean by "overall charge"? Series resistors are equivalent to a total resistor given by the sum $R_\text{tot} = R_1 + R_2 + \ldots = \sum_i R_i$.

An important condition to remember is that in an electrical circuit, all electrons travel in a closed loop. With a potential difference, current will flow in the loop at the same drift velocity. Adding a resistor slows the entire electron queue since the electrons are traveling in a loop and the velocity of each electron depends on the velocity of the electron ahead of it in the queue. Electrons do not travel through the different resistances in a circuit at different speeds. Flow depends on the total resistance.
Related:
Does the velocity (or Drift Velocity) of an electron decrease after passing through a resistor?


Why is current constant in a series circuit?

Current is uniform in a series circuit. That is, it is the same in various places along its circuit path. The word "constant" sometimes has the implication that something does not vary with time.
There are two distinct concepts that go by the name of current. The one you are probably most familiar with is conduction current, which is the movement of charges. A second kind of current is Maxwell's displacement current, which is simply a change in electric field intensity. This second kind of current is mostly associated with capacitors and antennas and lightning strikes.
A consequence of Maxwell's equations is that the total current (of both types) through a simple closed surface is $0$. (for the derivation see note (1).) If you choose that simple closed surface to enclose a node of a circuit, then you arrive at what is known as Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL). The algebraic sum of all the currents flowing into a circuit node is $0$.
If you apply KCL to two electrical components connected in series, you will see that each must carry the same current.
Note (1):
The total current passing through a simple closed surface is $0$.
Begin with Ampere's Law with Maxwell's addition
$$\nabla\times\vec{B}=\mu_0\left(\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\vec{V}}{\partial t}\right)$$
Take the divergence of both sides
$$\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\vec{B})=\mu_0\left(\nabla\cdot\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\nabla\cdot\vec{V}}{\partial t}\right)$$
The divergence of a curl is $0$, so the left hand side is zero, so
$$0=\nabla\cdot\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\nabla\cdot\vec{V}}{\partial t}$$
With some calculus, we arrive at the surface integral over any simple closed surface $\partial\Omega$ is 0.
$$0={\subset\!\supset}\llap{\iint}_{\partial\Omega}\vec{J}+\vec{J}_D\cdot d\vec{S} = 0$$
where $\vec{J}_D = \frac{\partial\vec{V}}{\partial t}$ is the displacement current density.
